# Обращение к определенным атрибутам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
<div class="TRP">
<h1>Top Rated Products</h1>
<div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/juice.jpg" alt="">
        <h1>Rose</h1>
        <a href="">learn more</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/juice.jpg" alt="">
        <h1>Rose</h1>
        <a href="">learn more</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/juice.jpg" alt="">
        <h1>Rose</h1>
        <a href="">learn more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как применить замену картинки после наведения на объект, допустим на `juice2.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов задать им отдельный `class` и по `class-у` производить те или иные действия...

```js
$('.img-wrap').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg')
  },
  function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/753/371608-svetik.jpg')
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img-wrap" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/753/371608-svetik.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
<img class="img-wrap" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/753/371608-svetik.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
<img class="img-wrap" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/753/371608-svetik.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
```

Comment: не все так просто. У меня еще уйма картинок на странице. Как применить только к данным трем?

Comment: @Antonio112009, нужно зацепиться за какую-то уникальную особенность. В данном случае, я вижу родительский элемент с классом = "TRP". В принципе, никто не мешает обращаться к элементам по их атрибутам и значениям этих атрибутов: `$('img[src="images/juice.jpg"]')`

Comment: @Deonis оо... Супер) Это уже меняет всю картину в целом.